# authenticating a grails server from android client

Tags: android, authentication, grails

I'm new to Grails and Android. I am developing an application where the server (Grails) provides user data and client (Android) authenticates and gets the data. The server has spring security and I'm trying to do a http post to send username and password.

The http command I'm using is `http://10.0.2.2:8080/test/j_spring_security_check?j_username=user1&j_password=pass1` and I'm using `@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` on the controller which sends data.

Without the security I'm able to access the data(grails app renders the data as Json and I'm using appropriate code on Android to display the json response). But it fails when the page is secured. This is for my final academic project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all put tour attention to request method to your web appliaction.
As far as I know you should send POST method request.
Second Spring security checks your cookies, especially parameter JSESSIONID you just make this parameter valid to Spring security having provided your credentials.
You can check it via some network analyzer.

I worked out similar task using HttpCleint embedded in Android. Here is code listing I used to  implement my own security system.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://yourwebbapp");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
            List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://yourwebbapp");

            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken1", "username"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IDToken2", "password"));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
            entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }

        } finally {
            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
            // shut down the connection manager to ensure
            // immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

Comment: It works good for form auth with Spring security, mayby you implemented authter method of authorization in your web application. Can you show your Spring security settings to make this issue resolved?

Comment: Another way you can apply grails guthentification plugin